# expression for "SelectLayerByAttribute_management" with value of a cursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I am currently struggling with the correct syntax for a SelectLayerByAttribute_management query, which is created iteratively by a cursor. I want to intersect each municipality from a polygon file containing the municipality boundaries with another polygon file (using arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management - it works so far). Currently my problem is that I cannot pass the cursor value containing the municipality name into the query.

```
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(county, "countyLyr")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(LASlist, "LASlistLyr")
reset_layers("countyLyr", "LASlistLyr")

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("countyLyr", ("NAME", "ICC", "BEZIRKSNUM"), """"ICC" = 'CH' AND "BEZIRKSNUM" = 'CH01040000'""") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #select = (row[0])
        #expression = "\"NAME\" = 'Steinmaur'"
        county = row[0]
        print(county)
        expression = "\"NAME\" = str(county)"
        print(expression)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("countyLyr",'NEW_SELECTION', expression)
        print(row[0])
        matchcount = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("countyLyr")[0])
        print(matchcount)
        if matchcount <> 0:
            arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("LASlistLyr",'INTERSECT', "countyLyr")
            matchcountlas = int(arcpy.GetCount_management("LASlistLyr")[0])
            print(str(matchcountlas) + ' LAS-Kacheln')
            #do something with the result
        else:
            print('Keine Selektion / Keine Daten')
```

If I put the name of the county in the form `expression = "\"NAME\" = 'Steinmaur'"` into the query , it works perfectly (but only for this county). When I output the cursor value `print(row[0])`, I also get the correct result (all counties). But when I combine the query with the cursor value I got unfurtunately the error message

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000358: Invalid expression

So my hopefully easy question how I can combine the cursor value with my querry, that I won't get the error message?

Comment: it seems that I found the solution by myself ... the right expression string is: `"\"NAME\" = '" + (row[0]) + "'"`. So the full command of selectLayerByAttribute is `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("countyLyr",'NEW_SELECTION', "\"NAME\" = '" + (row[0]) + "'")` it looks quite strange, but it works

Comment: Always use [AddFieldDelimiters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/addfielddelimiters.htm), look at the code sample.